# @HystrixCollapser null pointer exception on collapsed method

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

Hi I have problem with simply collapsed method:
My controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/collapsed/{id}")
public Car getFromServiceCollapsed(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception{
    Car result =  carService.getCollapsed(id).get();
    return result;
}
```

and service:

```
@HystrixCollapser(batchMethod = "getCollapsedCars",
        collapserProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "timerDelayInMilliseconds", value = "100"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "requestCache.enabled", value = "true")
        },
        collapserKey = "getCollapsed")
public Future<Car> getCollapsed(Integer id){
    return null;
}

@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "getCircuitService",
        threadPoolKey = "getCircuitService",
        threadPoolProperties = {
                @HystrixProperty(name = "coreSize", value = "10"),
                @HystrixProperty(name = "maximumSize", value = "14"),
                @HystrixProperty(name = "maxQueueSize", value = "20")
        },
        commandProperties = {
                @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.strategy", value = "THREAD"),
                @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "2000"),
                @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.timeout.enabled", value = "true")
        },
        fallbackMethod = "getDefault")
private List<Car> getCollapsedCars(List<Integer> ids){
    LOGGER.debug("Collapse for {}", ids.size());
    return ids.stream().map(this::getCar).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And it's throwing exception when calling controller:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCollapser$3.call(HystrixCollapser.java:398) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCollapser$3.call(HystrixCollapser.java:382) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
```

But when I modify controller with initialize HystrixRequestContext on each controller call it starts working but not so well - Service method getCollapsedCars always log: "Collapse for 1" - but I'm sending 20 RQ one by one with 1 ms delly.

Modified controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/collapsed/{id}")
public Car getFromServiceCollapsed(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception{
    HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
    Car result =  carService.getCollapsed(id).get();
    context.shutdown();
    return result;
}
```

How to make collapsed command working ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly same issue. Requests were not getting grouped in batches.
However the problem was HystrixRequestContext, as this is local to your request.

Please remove local HystrixRequestContext creation and add it as scope to collapser.

@HystrixCollapser(scope = com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCollapser.Scope.GLOBAL, batchMethod =..............)

and voila!!!